# Excel VBA Add Dynamic Frame To Another Dynamic Frame

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, controls, userform

How do I add a dynamically created frame to another dynamically created frame?

Adding the parent frame works:

`Set c = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "newcontrol1", True)`

Adding the child frame causes an error:

`Set c = UserForm1.Controls("newcontrol1").Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "newcontrol2", True)`

The child frame is not added directly after the parent, so I need a way of referencing/accessing the parent frame's `Controls` at a later stage (essentially a working equivalent of the above expression).

`...UserForm1.Controls("newcontrol1").Controls...` would work if `"newcontrol1"` was a normal frame. I know dynamically created controls can't be referenced in the same way that normal controls can be, and that they aren't created with events as standard, however even a dynamically created frame should have a `Controls` property... right?

I feel as though I've managed to do this before, but I can't find any examples of this online.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Mr. J

Answer (score 0):

Changing this line:

```
Set c = UserForm1.Controls("newcontrol1").Controls.Add("Forms.Frame.1", "newcontrol2", True)
```

To:

```
Set c = UserForm1.Controls("newcontrol1").Add("Forms.Frame.1", "newcontrol2", True)
```

This worked for me. I believe the issue was the fact that you used .Controls twice.

Comment: This still doesn't work for me if `"newcontrol1"` was created dynamically. Was it a dynamic control when you tried it? I tried your code with `"newcontrol1"` as a normal control and it works both your way **without** `.Controls` _and_ my initial way **with** `.Controls` so I don't think this makes a difference.

Comment: I've tried and tested it and it worked for me, I created the first frame through the click of a button and the second through another button click..?

Comment: Apologies yes creating one and then the other straight after does work, with or without a reference to `.Controls`. I think my issue is a bit more complicated. It turns out you can only `.Add` new frames to the most recently created frame. Due to my build order, I was trying to access a frame after I had already added a number of other parent frames. I've now since changed my build order so the the child frame immediately follows the parent and this seems to work. It just means that everything needs to be built in order. I'm sure there's a more efficient way of doing this though.